# CnosDB date_trunc, increase function throws an error when used

Tags: cnosdb

```
usage_schema ❯ select tenant, database, date_trunc('minute', time) time_bucket, increase(time, value order by time) addition, node_id from http_data_out where time >= (now() - INTERVAL '120') group by tenant, database, node_id;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Projection references non-aggregate values: Expression http_data_out.time could not be resolved from available columns: http_data_out.tenant, http_data_out.database, http_data_out.node_id, increase(http_data_out.time,http_data_out.value) ORDER BY ([http_data_out.time ASC NULLS LAST])"}
```

link: [enter link description here](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.3/reference/sql.html#date-trunc)

Excuse me, I encountered the aforementioned error while using the date_trunc and increase functions in cnosdb. The documentation link is also attached above. Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `database` field has been removed in 2.3.4

https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/pull/1625

Because this field can confuse people about the metric